# Is it possible to switch to release mode automatically if I publish a vs project?

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, debugging, release

I'm obviously developing in debug mode. If I'm starting with the standard run command (F5) my project should start in debug mode but if I publish my project it should automatically switch in release mode. Is this possible somehow, maybe even with scripting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could easily write a macro in VBA that was bound to a command in VS which switched to release mode, did your full rebuild, and fired off any other publishing/packaging required.  I've done this before.

The object model for [VS automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b54865a.aspx) is very feature complete.

---

Edit:

Debug/Release in VS are configuration properties.  Here's the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228959(VS.80).aspx) on accessing/modifying this.

Once you've set that, you should be able to use [DTE.ExecuteCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte._dte.executecommand.aspx) to start a build (or do anything else that's available via menus, etc).

Comment: Thanks Reed, nice idea (although I hoped it would be *easier*). Do you know a link which describes the required commands?

Comment: I've played a little bit with the macro recorder and think that I'll get along. Thanks.

Comment: Keselogof, could you please share more info on it?